# Connect local computers without local static IP

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip-address

I have 3 PCs, one is server others are clients. Clients connects to server by entering the server local IP. All works good but problem occurs when the router restarts and server get assigned a different local IP. Now, need to enter IP address again of server in clients. I can solve this by using a local static IP but is it possible to connect without setting local static IP ?

Edit:
Using TCP Socket.

Comment: Can you go by the hostname?

Comment: What is the nature of the connection between the clients and the server? TCP? UDP? some higher level protocol?

Comment: Why not use local dns name ?

Comment: Wow people're overreacting for asking this question.

Comment: @xmenW.K. not overreacting, asking for more details ;)

Comment: 2 people voted to close the question. Dont know who else will ;)

Comment: how do you establish connections? `Socket`? `WCF`?

Comment: What is TCP Socket? `TcpClient` and `TcpListener`? `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` ?

Comment: The app is not yet completely written, its currently is just for testing. Anything can be used later, currently all I need is to connect to the server without static IP Address. I hope I've cleared things :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the hostname for connecting to remote computer rather its IP address.
You will have to rely on DNS lookup though.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs because you use DHCP function of router. D of DHCP stands for "Dynamic", so IP addresses may be changed in some occasion.

The most simple solution is 'Not to use DHCP'.

[Detail of solution]

Assign fixed IP addresses for your PCs, and use that IP addresses to access among them.

Usually, router uses local IP address in range from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255 and 192.168.1.1 is used for router itself.

You may be able to use IP addresses 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.4 for 3 PCs respectively.

Comment: True but asking this to normal users can be hard to them. Not all users can define static IP address. Thats why I left this solution to be last. Thank you :)

Comment: If new IP address is assined to the server by DHCP function of the router, how can you know the new IP address? If you know the MAC address of the server, you can use ARP protocol to get IP address of the router. Unfortunately most of user had never programmed code usign lower layer protocol like ARP.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do, how about you give the server an endpoint that is unique, something like

```
http://<server>/isthisme
```

Then you just go through all IP adresses in the network and then try to reach that endpoint. The one where it returns `200` that is your server.

To get the IPs is a bit complicated, you first need to get your own IP, then go with the subnetmask over it and at the end you can just go the following way:

```
for (int p1 = 1; p1 < netmask[0]; p1++) {
    for (int p2 = 1; p2 < netmask[1]; p2++) {
        for (int p3 = 1; p3 < netmask[2]; p3++) {
            for (int p4 = 1; p4 < netmask[3]; p4++) {
                var ip = new IPAdress(p1, p2, p3, p4);
                if (trytoreach(ip)) {
                    return ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a way you could go by. It is not optimized so feel free ^^

Here is a gist with the method https://gist.github.com/DerKnerd/ff9c34087955efce0970. Just the part with the subnetmask you need to figure out. I don't guarantee that it will work though.

Comment: That sounds good, can you tell what method is that to get all local computer IPs.

Comment: @xmenW.K. check the update. I once had the problem with raspberry PIs. I used something like that to get the IPs.